# How to incorparate properties of an enum (the values of its fields) automatically into its JavaDoc

Tags: java, enums

Is it possible to incorporate properties of an enum (the values of its fields) automatically into its JavaDoc?

**Example:**

Given an enum

```
public enum Planet {
    MERCURY (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6),
    VENUS   (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6),
    EARTH   (5.976e+24, 6.37814e6),
    MARS    (6.421e+23, 3.3972e6),
    JUPITER (1.9e+27,   7.1492e7),
    SATURN  (5.688e+26, 6.0268e7),
    URANUS  (8.686e+25, 2.5559e7),
    NEPTUNE (1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);

    private final double mass;   // in kilograms
    private final double radius; // in meters

    Planet(double mass, double radius) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}
```

The JavaDoc of MERCURY should automatically list the values, i.e. 3.303e+23 and 2.4397e6. It would be nice if one could define a template, like

```
Defines the enum with mass {$mass} and radius {$radius}.
```

Comment: You can say `Mercury has mass {@value MERCURY_MASS} kg and radius {@value MERCURY_RADIUS} m` assuming those constants are defined, but I guess that is not what you are looking for? You are looking for a way to write this just once?

Comment: Yes. Your workaround would require to define a separate constant MERCURY_MASS. That would work, and is even a bit better to duplicate the value in the JavaDoc. So it is maybe "halfway".